# Expressing the probability of a random vector being in a random set as a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathbb{P}_X$ be its distribution. Let $\{A_y : y \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ be some collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $Y$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}_X(A_Y) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_Y}(X) \mid Y]$, where $\mathbb{I}_{A_y}$ is the indicator function of $A_y$? It seems reasonable to me, but I don't see how to prove this.

Comment: I don't get this. $X$ takes values in $\mathbb R^{\color{red}{n}}\,.$ How do you define $\mathbb I_{A_Y}(X)$ when $A_Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^{\color{red}{m}}\,?$ Even if this was a typo and $n=m\,,$ what is $\mathbb P_X(A_Y)$ to begin with? The distribution $\mathbb P_X$ of $X$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and assigns values to ordinary Borel sets in $\mathbb R^n\,,$ not to "random" subsets.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry, that was a typo. I also added the qualifier "Borel" so that $A_y$ is a Borel set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and assuming a suitable measurability condition on the map $y\mapsto A_y$, the answer is yes.

To begin with, we formulate the measurability of $y\mapsto A_y$ in terms of the map $(x, y) \mapsto \mathbb{I}[x \in A_y]$. That is, we say that $y \mapsto A_y$ is measurable iff the map $(x, y) \mapsto \mathbb{I}[x \in A_y]$ is jointly measurable.

Now, we assume

1. $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and
2. $y \mapsto A_y$ is measurable.

Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{A_Y}(X) \mid Y]
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}[X \in A_Y] \mid Y] \tag{1} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}[X \in A_y]]_{y = Y} \tag{2} \\
&= \mathbb{P}_X(A_y)_{y = Y} \tag{3}\\
&= \mathbb{P}_X(A_Y) \tag{4}
\end{align*}

- $\text{(1)}$ : The indicator function is rephrased.
- $\text{(2)}$ : This holds because of the independence of $X$ and $Y$.
- $\text{(3)}$ : [Change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula).
- $\text{(4)}$ : Substituting $y = Y$.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late response. Where does the argument use the second assumption, the assumption that $y \mapsto A_y$ is measurable?

Comment: @VKV, The assumption is used to ensure that $\mathbb{I}_{A_Y}(X)$ is indeed a random variable (i.e., a measurable function), that all the probabilistic quantities are well-defined, and that all the results mentioned are applicable.